# Passing info from UINavigationController to embedded UIViewController

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller, segue, uistoryboardsegue

## Synopsis

Because of the way I am not getting my app to pass data as I intend, I am lead to ask the following questions:

- In general, how can I pass data from a Navigation Controller to its
  imbedded View Controller?
- Specifically, does the `prepareForSegue`
  method in a Navigation Controller ever get called?  If so, how?

## The Setup

I have the following:

- **A View** titled *User View Controller*,
  linked to a custom class `JRMUserViewController` (which extends `UIViewController`).
  This view is imbedded in:
- **A Navigation View** titled *Navigation To User View*,
  linked to a custom class `JRMNavigationToUserViewController` (which extends `UINavigationController`).
  *IMPORTANT NOTE:*
  To start with, I did not have *User View Controller* imbedded in the Navigation Controller.  The Navigation Controller and its linked class did not exist.
- **A Table View** titled *Issue Table View Controller*,
  linked to a custom class `JRMIssuesTableViewController` (which extends `UITableViewController`).
- **A Button** linked to **a Modal Segue** that goes to the *Navigaton To User View*.
  The Segue is identified by the text "`IssuesToUserView`".

[image: StoryBoard Setup]

## Intended Functionality

The idea is that when I am on the *Issue Table View Controller*, I can click on the button and it will take me to the *User View Controller*, where I will see the current user's avatar, and a label with the current user's full name.

To accomplish this (before I embeded the *User View Controller* in the Navigation Controller), I passed data from the `JRMIssuesTableViewController` to the `JRMUserViewController` in the former's prepareForSegue method:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"\nSEGUE IDENTIFIER:\n%@", [segue identifier]);
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"IssuesToUserView"]) {
        JRMUserViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        vc.currentUser = self.currentUser;
        NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[vc.currentUser.avatarUrls objectForKey:@"48x48"]];
        NSLog(@"\nURL:\n%@", url);
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        [vc.view addSubview:vc.avatar];
        [vc.avatar setImage:[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data]];
        vc.userLabel.text = vc.currentUser.displayName;    
   }
}
```

**And it worked.**  Clicking the button on the first view took me to the second view, where the current user's information was displayed:

[image: Issue Table View]

[image: User View -- Working]

## Unexpected Behavior

**After this, out of necessity**, I had to embed *User View Controller* in the Navigation Controller that I mentioned earlier.  Now of course, after doing this, I had uncaught exceptions at runtime because, in my overridden prepareForSegue, I was sending messages to the Navigation Controller instead of to the User View Controller.  To fix this, I extended `UINavigationController`, naming it `JRMNavigationToUserViewController`, and linked the Navigation View to it, as I mentioned in the setup.

Then, figuring that a `UINavigationController` would call its own `prepareForSegue` before going to its embedded View, I overrode the `prepareForSegue` method in `JRMNavigationToUserViewController`:

```
- (id)passValuesToDesitinationOfSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue {
    NSLog(@"Calling [JRMNavigationToUserViewController passValuesToDestinationOfSegue]");
    JRMUserViewController *destination = [segue destinationViewController];
    destination.server = self.server;
    destination.currentUser = self.currentUser;
    destination.avatar = self.avatar;
    [destination.view addSubview:destination.avatar];
    destination.userLabel = self.userLabel;
    return destination;
}

#pragma mark - Navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Calling [JRMNavigationToUserViewController prepareForSegue]");
    [self passValuesToDesitinationOfSegue:segue];
}
```

This time, when I clicked on the button, the *User View Controller* did not receive the data.  It looked like this:

[image: User View -- Not Working]

Apparently, the `prepareForSegue` method in `JRMNavigationToUserViewController` was never called, as it would have logged the message:

```
Calling [JRMNavigationToUserViewController prepareForSegue]
Calling [JRMNavigationToUserViewController passValuesToDestinationOfSegue]
```

I could not find these lines printed anywhere in the console.

## Summary

Here again are my questions:

- In general, how can I pass data from a Navigation Controller to its
  imbedded View Controller?
- Specifically, does the `prepareForSegue`
  method in a Navigation Controller ever get called?  If so, how?

Comment: Navigation controllers don't generally have their own content -- they expect to manage a stack of other view controllers, with the view of the controller currently at the top of the stack being displayed. If you've subclassed `UINavigationController` such that it displays its own content, you're surely making life much more difficult for yourself than it needs to be. Can you address the reason that you decided to subclass `UINavigationController`?

Comment: I subclassed it so I could override `prepareForSegue` in an attempt to pass data to the imbedded view.  I suspect, however, that this reveals how much I misunderstand about how UINavigationController` works.  Which is why I asked the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misusing `UINavigationController` here. Take a look at your storyboard: you've got a table controller that somehow presents a navigation controller, which in turn has a user controller as its root controller. I think what you want is to have the navigation controller contain the table controller, and have taps on the table trigger a push segue to the user view controller. So, the nav controller should be on the left with the table controller in the middle and the user controller on the right.

Then, the `-prepareForSegue:sender:` method in the table controller would be written such that it looks at the selected cell and sets the corresponding attributes of the user controller (which is the segue's destination).

Comment: You're right.  I got rid of the Navigation Controller, and it worked (there was already a navigation controller upstream from the Issues view).  Your answer has helped me understand `UINavigationController` better.  Thanks!